# Difficulties extending generated_attribute.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to extend **railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generated_attribute.rb** in order to create two new types. I need this because when running

```
rails g scaffold Contact address:hidden title:select gender:select first_name:string surname:string email:string phones:string
```

I need Rails to understand that it must NOT create a field for attribute **address** and must generate **HTML select** tags for **title** and **gender**.

I wrote the following code:

```
require 'rails/generators/generated_attribute'

module Rails
  module Generators
    class GeneratedAttribute       

      class << self

        def hidden?
          @field_type == :nofield
        end

        def select?
          @field_type == :select
        end

      end

      def field_type
        @field_type ||= case type
          when :integer              then :number_field
          when :float, :decimal      then :text_field
          when :time                 then :time_select
          when :datetime, :timestamp then :datetime_select
          when :date                 then :date_select
          when :text                 then :text_area
          when :boolean              then :check_box
          when :hidden               then :nofield
          when :select               then :select
          else
            :text_field
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

and put it under **lib/generators/my_attributes_generator/my_attributes_generator.rb**, but when I run the **rails g scaffold** command above I still get a

```
(erb):25:in `block in template': undefined method `hidden?' for #<Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute:0xcdcf83c> (NoMethodError)
```

at the point where my scaffold template says

```
<%- if attribute.hidden? -%>
```

I tried many ways but nothing helped. Now I'm even questioning myself if this I want to do is possible.

Comment: In which file is this line? `<%- if attribute.hidden? -%>`

Comment: It is in the form template used to scaffold my forms, i.e., lib/templates/erb/scaffold/_form.html.erb

Comment: My goal is exactly this: may test in the form template and exclude the fields marked with :hidden and display as `<select>` the fields marked with :select.

Comment: Not yet... Stilll with some errors, but it is better now. I'm going to post the errors soon. Just too busy to do it now, but I feel we are in the right path now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take out the `hidden?` method from the singleton class and define it as normal method in the class `GeneratedAttribute`. Because by defining the `hidden?` method in the `class << self; end` can be accessed only by  `GeneratedAttribute.hidden?`

```
require 'rails/generators/generated_attribute'

module Rails
  module Generators
    class GeneratedAttribute     
        def hidden?
          @field_type == :nofield
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Then this code `<%- if attribute.hidden? -%>` will work.

Let me know if it helps!